# Is it possible to select multiple cells of UICollectionView using swipe?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to use Swipe-Gesture in UICollectionView for selecting multiple cells, how can I implement this?

Thank you

Resolve Using UIPanGestureRecognizer & allowsMultipleSelection

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panning = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanning:)];
panning.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
panning.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self.storeLayoutGrid addGestureRecognizer:panning];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a swipe to select multiple individual cells. Then the answer is YES. With a gesture recognizer and setting the cell as selected = YES. Add the gesture recognizer to the cell and make sure your collection view has multipleSelection enabled.

Comment: Thanx.  in cellForItemAtIndexPath - 

 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeUp:)];
    swipeUpRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [swipeUpRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];  But How to get how many rows are selected by swipe??

Comment: track the selected cells using the collectoview wasSelected wasDeselected delegate methods.

Comment: I am not getting if we are tracking the wasSelected & wasDeselected method then we have to click on every cell but I want to track via Swipe Gesture??